# Elements affected JavaScript equivalent

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

I would like a JavaScript solution for measuring the number of affected DOM nodes in a period of time. 
The solution I'm looking for is much alike the Elements affected property in the Chrome toolbar.
Because I want to measure this client side when my application is in production, I cant use the Chrome toolbar.
I already tried `document.getElementsByTagName("*").length` but that only gives me the current amount.
So if I'd to remove 2 elements and add 3, it will say that 1 node was affected where in reality there were 5.
Any ideas/hacks?

Comment: You do know that you typo'd `length`, right?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, that is my standard typo. I can't seem to type it correctly at the first try :P But the typo does not solve the problem I'm experiencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently implemented in Firefox as `MutationObserver` and in Chrome as the vendor-prefixed `WebKitMutationObserver`:

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    // fired when a mutation occurs
    console.log(mutations, observer);
    // ...
});

// define what element should be observed by the observer
// and what types of mutations trigger the callback
observer.observe(document, {
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true
  //...
});
```

This example listens for DOM changes on `document` and its entire subtree, and it will fire on changes to element attributes as well as structural changes.  The draft spec has a full list of valid [mutation properties](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutationobserver).